# Netflix Hystrix Support

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

> Netflix Hystrix seems to be going to a maintenance mode. Would like to
>   understand what is SAP's take on this? Will there be any change going
>   forward?

As per the S4SDK blog Click [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/23/step-5-resilience-with-hystrix/)! , SAP S4 cloud archetype is using Hystrix library for resilience.  From the Netflix Hystrix library,https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix, it states that there won't be any new developments and it continues to be in maintenance mode. They have recommended using resilience4j going forward.
Need to understand, what is SAP's recommendation going forward in terms of S4SDK for using Hystrix?

Comment: Hi Arun, I updated my answer below with the latest changes regarding our resilience framework choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with version 3.0.0 of the SAP Cloud SDK we replaced Hystrix with Resilience4J as our go-to resilience framework.

For more details checkout our updated tutorial [here](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-resilience.html).

---

We are currently heavily investigating into replacing Hystrix with Resilience4J.

As a workaround you could handle the resilience of your commands yourself using Resilience4J (wrapping your logic into the decorators needed) instead of extending the SDKs `ErpCommand`.

I will update this answer when we can share details/results.

Comment: Please note that this would come with the downside that the [sdk pipeline](https://github.com/sap/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline) would not recognize Resilience4J as of now and thus will complain about your code not being resilient. We are aware of this issue.